# PHP How to echo string that starts with "<"

Tags: php, html, string, echo

I cannot echo a string that starts with `<`.

If my string is `adasda<asdasd` it stops printing after the `<`. I don't know what else can I do to stop with this.

This is what I'm trying to echo...

```
$flightHTML="<div class='flight'></div>"; 
die($flightHTML);
```

Comment: You are trying to echo `html` with no content? or you are trying to echo `<div class='flight'>adasda<asdasd</div>`?

Answer (score 2):

It *is* printing. But because `<` is a special character in HTML the browser thinks you've opened an HTML tag and is omitted the invalid tag from rendering. You need to escape that character with [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

```
$string = htmlspecialchars('adasda<asdasd');
```